# Checking the condition $\mathcal{L}_p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$N$ is said to has the property $\mathcal L_p$ if for all prime divisors $r$ of $N$, there is an integer $l_p(r, a)$ such that

$$r^{p-1} \equiv N^{(p-1)l_p(r,a)} \mod p^a  $$

I'm trying to prove that for all prime $p \geq 3$, $N$ has the property $\mathcal L_p$ if and only if $\nu_p(r^{p-1} - 1) \geq \nu_p(N^{p-1} - 1)$.

This is what I have proved so far:

If $N$ has the property $\mathcal L_p$ and $u = \nu_p(N^{p-1} - 1)$, then $$r^{p-1} \equiv N^{(p-1)l_r(r, u)} \mod p^u \Rightarrow $$
$$r^{p-1} - 1 \equiv N^{(p-1)l_r(r, u)} - 1 = (N^{p-1} - 1)(...) \equiv 0 \mod p^u \Rightarrow$$
$$\nu_p(r^{p-1} - 1) \geq \nu_p(N^{p-1} - 1) = u$$

I'm having trouble to prove the converse. Any help with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "$a$" ? If N has $\mathcal L_p$ property, does that mean for all integers $a$ that modulo equivalence should be satisfied by some number $ l_p(r,a)$ or does that mean there is an integer "$a$" which provides that modulo equivalence is satisfied by some number $ l_p(r,a)$. If you mean the secondary, then how can you choose $u$ in your proof of first side and say this modulo equivalence is satisfied for this particular $u$.

Comment: @Merdanov, it means that for all positive integers $a$, there is such integer $l_p(r, a)$.

Comment: By the way I'm reading this from Henri Cohen's book 'A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory'. It's Lemma 9.1.14 on page 455. @Merdanov check it out if you like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\nu_p(r^{p-1} - 1) \geq \nu_p(N^{p-1} - 1)$,

Let's say $\nu_p(N^{p-1} - 1)=u$ and $\nu_p(r^{p-1} - 1)=u+v$ where $u,v\geq 0$.

Then for $a\leq u$, we can choose $l_p (r, a)=1$.

For $u\leq a \leq u+v$, we can choose $l_p (r, a)=p^{a-1}$ because $\phi(p^{a})=p^{a-1}(p-1)$.

For $a \gt u+v $,

We should prove that $r^{p-1}-1 \equiv N^{(p-1)l_p(r, a)}-1 \pmod {p^a}$ for some $l_p(r, a)$.

We know that $r^{p-1}-1 \equiv p^{u+v}k \pmod {p^a}$ for $1\leq k\leq p^{a-u-v}$ and $(k,p)=1$. So there is $\phi(p^{a-u-v})$ possibility for k.
By LTE lemma we know that $\nu_p(N^{(p-1)l_p(r,a)} - 1)=\nu_p(N^{p-1} - 1)+\nu_p(l_p(r,a))=u+\nu_p(l_p(r,a))$

Let's look at $u_m(r,a)=p^vm$ where m goes over $1\leq m\leq p^{a-u-v}$ such that $(m,p)=1$.(So there is $\phi(p^{a-u-v})$ different $u_m$s)

For all $u_m$,

$\nu_p(N^{(p-1)u_m} - 1)=u+\nu_p(u_m)=u+v$

$$\Rightarrow N^{(p-1)u_m} - 1 \equiv p^{u+v}t \pmod {p^a}$$ for some t such that $1\leq t \leq p^{a-u-v}$ and $(t,p)=1$

Let's take any $m_1,m_2$ such that $1\leq m_1\lt m_2\leq p^{a-u-v}$. If $N^{(p-1)u_{m_1}} - 1 \equiv N^{(p-1)u_{m_2}}-1\pmod {p^a}$

$$\Rightarrow N^{(p-1)u_{m_1}}(N^{(p-1)(u_{m_2}-u_{m_1})}-1) \equiv 0 \pmod {p^{a}}$$
$$\Rightarrow N^{(p-1)(u_{m_2}-u_{m_1})}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod {p^{a}}$$
$$\Rightarrow u+v+\nu_p(m_2-m_1)=u+\nu_p(u_{m_2}-u_{m_1})= \nu_p( N^{(p-1)(u_{m_2}-u_{m_1})}-1)\geq a$$
$$\Rightarrow m_2-m_1 \geq p^{a-u-v} \Rightarrow \Leftarrow$$

So for all $\phi(p^{a-u-v})$ different $u_m$, $N^{(p-1)u_{m}}-1$ goes to different rezidue classes which covers all rezidue classes as of the form $p^{u+v}k$ for $1\leq k\leq p^{a-u-v}$ and $(k,p)=1$. So there exist $u_m$ such that we can choose $l_p(r,a)=u_m$.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful!